# How to sign Jars in ANT with a token based Certificate

Tags: java, ant, code-signing

The Certificate Authority I use for my Jar signing certificates -- GlobalSign -- has switched to issuing token based code signing Certificates. These require setting jarsigner's providerClass and providerArg options. Ant's signjar task (I have checked documentation for Ant 1.10.1) does not support these parameters. Given that, how can I automate this Task in Ant? Thanks everyone!

Comment: Since ANT 1.10.6, there are new parameters available(`providername`, `providerclass` and `providerarg`). Try them out.

Answer (score 1):

I just happened to encouter the same problem (same provider too ;-)
I had to resort to using the  task in Ant, as follows:

```
<exec executable="${jarsigner}"> 
    <arg line="-keystore ${signkeyNew.keystore} -storetype ${signkeyNew.storetype} -storepass ${signkeyNew.storepass} -providerClass ${signkeyNew.providerClass} -providerArg ${signkeyNew.providerArg} -tsa ${signkey.tsaurl} ${build.bundle-jar} ${signkeyNew.alias}" />
</exec>
```

(aliases mentioned in "${xxx}" have been defined as  values before)